# How to draw multiple centric circles in R

Tags: r, plot, geometry, plotrix

Hey I want to draw several circles in R with different radius.

I did this with 'plotrix' and draw.circle:

```
draw.circle (0,0,1)
draw.circle (0,0,1.5)
draw.circle (0,0,2)
...
```

Do you know a faster and smarter way to do that?

Comment: What constitutes "faster and smarter"? Putting the calls into a loop? I think you need to improve your question to get meaningful answers. Otherwise you risk it being closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`draw.circle` seems to accept a vector of inputs, so use whatever function is convenient to make your sequence of inputs and pass that to the function.

```
plot(0,0,type = "n", xlim = c(-10,10), ylim = c(-10,10))
draw.circle (0,0,seq(0,4,.5))
```

[image]

Comment: @dason - aspect ratio issue, I can't remember where the setting to change it is, but will make the plot " look " like a circle...

Comment: set to equal aspect ratio with: `asp = 1`